# How many ways can we get 2 a's and 2 b's from aabb?

Tags: combinatorics

We have the following group: $aabb$

It is commutative, so abab is the same as aabb.

I have figured out this is a combinatorics question.  Because abab is the same as aabb.  I was how to solve these problems with the blank slot method, i.e. _ _ _ _.

If I do this manually, it's clear to me the answer is 6,

aabb
abab
abba
baba
bbaa
baab

Which is the same as $$\binom{4}{2}$$

But I don't really understand why this is true? How is this supposed to be done without brute forcing the question?

Comment: How is $aabb$ a group? If $abab = aabb$, then why are you counting them separately?

Comment: It is a subquestion from another question.  I understand how to brute force it, but had trouble with it mathematically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have four slots. Choose two of them to be `a`, and the other two will be forced to be `b`. There are $\binom 4 2$ ways to choose two slots from four, giving the answer.

Comment: Isn't this a combination with repetition problem with? Since otherwise we have $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ to choose from? I don't understand how you can choose 2 of them to be a.  How is it possible to pick? Since it could pick one a and one b instead of two a's.

Comment: Also, couldn't the same logic be applied with choosing 2 of them to be a, and one of them to be be? But 4 choose 3 $\ne$ 4 choose 2

Comment: Not really. You have four slots, and four objects to fill them with. Two of the objects are ```a```, and are indistinguishable, and two are ```b``` and are also indistinguishable. For each possible arrangement, specifying where the ```a```s are forces the ```b```s to be in the other two slots, since there are four slots and you must use two of each letter.

Answer (score -1):

This is a permutation of $4$ objects with $2$ groups of $2$ identical elements. Answer is therefore $\frac{4!}{(2! \times 2!)}$

Or, this can be also the problem of selecting $2$ places out of $4$ to replace $b$ with $a$ in the string $bbbb$, in which case the answer is $\binom{4}{2}$